# Displaying image from MySQL other than echoing

Tags: php, html, image, mysqli

Is there another way to put image from MySQL to html other than echoing it like this:

```
  echo "<img src='images/" . $row['event_image'] . "' height='200' width='320' class=responsivez> ";
```

Im trying to put the image path onto the html  tag. The getImage.php displays my image path but when called on the next page the image doesnt display. Am i missing some important syntax?

```
<img src="images/getImage.php?" width="175" height="200" />
```

getImage.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","blast");
if (!$con) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 
$state='Johor';
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from blast_events where 
event_state='$state'");

if (!$result) {
die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else{    
}
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo $row["event_image"];
?>
```

Comment: Do *cmd+u* (on Mac) or *ctrl+u* (on Windows), and see if the link in the `src` attribute is correct or not.

Comment: You're going about this in the exact right way (aside from parameterisation); echoing out an `<img>` tag. Having said that, `$row['event_image']` shouldn't give you `getImage.php?`. Is that in your table row? You should be storing something like `image001.png`. Then your `<img>` tag will map out correctly (assuming the relevant image is on the server).

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes it is. event_image is the image column name on the database. the getImage.php is displaying the image's name, .png

Answer (score 0):

Try to Output the image instead of just a path:

```
   header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
   readfile($row["event_image"]); // make sure the path is valid not only filename.
// echo $row["event_image"];
```